# Unwanted characters appear in word document after using save as

Tags: microsoft-word

When I finish doing modifications and save the document using 'save as' gibberish in an unknown language (looks like Chinese) appear along with some of the words being jumbled and repeated.

> “Ranil, Ccome, the food is readyLanka.  thshoutedScreamed. It has been more >than fifteen minutes without an answer. ˊꎀˊꕀˊ꜀ˊur drunk here, the kids are >starving.vi
>   “here, the kids are starving.ving.s wsarong,sarong; did you take it by any >chance?g.
>     “did you take it by any chance?g.ving.s without an answer. ˊꎀ>ˊꕀˊ꜀ˊueverydayevery

In addition the original copy has gone missing, i.e. it cannot be found.
Can anyone tell me what has happened? This is a very large document and all pages of it are affected like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say document got corrupted. Reason could be anything like corrupted file system, bad drive, lack of disk space and so on. You can try 7 Zip or similar software to extract some information from your Word document. You might find this tutorial useful: http://www.howtogeek.com/50628/easily-extract-images-text-and-embedded-files-from-an-office-2007-document/